# load resource directory in jar file

Tags: java, image, jar, directory, photos

I found this code and I'm trying to adapt it to my project.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Album {

     static boolean contr = false;  
     static String path = "photos/";
     static int MAX;
     static String []imgName;
     static JLabel label = new JLabel();
     static JMenuBar mBar = new JMenuBar();
     static JMenu mn = new JMenu("open here ");
     static JMenuItem []menuItem;
     static JFrame fot = new JFrame();
     static JButton back = new JButton(" back ");


    public static void Album() {
        if (contr==true){
            fot.setVisible(true);
        }
        else{
            JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true); 
            File directory = new File(path);
            if (!directory.exists()) {
                System.err.println("The specified directory doesn't exist!!");
                err.err("fail.jpg");
            }
            try
            {
               UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            }  catch (Exception e) {
                // Do nothing
            }
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            label.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            mBar.updateUI();
            mn.updateUI();
            // Filter out the Images
            imgName = directory.list(new FilenameFilter() {
                String[] readFormat = ImageIO.getReaderFormatNames();

                @Override
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < readFormat.length; i++) {
                        if (name.endsWith(readFormat[i])) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            MAX = imgName.length;
            if (MAX == 0) {
                System.err.println("OOps , no images");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            //Limit the maximunm entries to 10
            if (MAX > 19) {
                MAX = 19;
            }
            menuItem = new JMenuItem[MAX];
            for (int i = 0; i < menuItem.length; i++) {
                menuItem[i] = new JMenuItem(imgName[i].substring(0, imgName[i].lastIndexOf(".")), new ImageIcon(getImage(path + imgName[i]).getScaledInstance(32, 32, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
                menuItem[i].updateUI();
                mn.add(menuItem[i]);
                menuItem[i].setActionCommand(imgName[i]);
                menuItem[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getImage(path + ae.getActionCommand())));
                    }
                });
            }
            mBar.add(mn);
            fot.setJMenuBar(mBar);
            fot.add(new JScrollPane(label));
            fot.add(back, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
            Dimension scrDim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            fot.setSize(scrDim.width-250 , scrDim.height-50);
            fot.setVisible(true);
            fot.setTitle("photo album");
            fot.setResizable(false);
            fot.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            fot.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {   //back
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    fot.setVisible(false);
                    contr=true;
                    menu.menu();
                }
            });
        }      
    }

    // Get the Image from the disk
    public static Image getImage(String fileName) {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Error loading Image : " + fileName);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

I have to export all in a .jar file, running it from eclipse work properly, while once exported .jar file is not working. The problem is that I can not find the photos/ folder , it is a second folder of resources, but also trying to the root is not working. Instead, it can read both of eclipse that in .jar file, each image passed as a parameter, as for calling the next class that displays an error message in a image:

```
err.err("fail.jpg");
```

the pattern of project folders is as follows:

project:

- src (classes)
- source (images)
- photos (photos)

All pathname are correct, als "fail.jpg".
Are weeks that I'm looking for a solution, I need to know how to upload images directly from a folder of resources to make them work directly in the .jar file. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using `getResourceAsStream("/fail.jpg")` method to get your file. An example would look like

```
InputStream inputStream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/fail.jpg");
```

Your jpg file should be in your source folder for this example.

Instead of Main you can use any class in your jar-file.